# What is the latest update on V-Leaflet compatibility for Vaadin 10+?

Tags: vaadin8, vaadin14

I am aware that V-Leaflet add on works only till(or for) Vaadin 8. I saw the last post from the author 3 years back that development for V-Leaflet is LeafletJS for Flow is in progress for Vaadin 10+ in the link https://vaadin.com/directory/component/v-leaflet

It lacks a lot of features as per his statement, however. To migrate from Vaadin 8 to Vaadin 14 with V-Leaflet features, what is the current alternative?

I really request the author/Vaadin support team to give a good solution without compromising on the usage of v-leaflet but still migrate to Vaadin 14 LTS. V-Leaflet features are needed for our project but in Vaadin 14 or the next LTS versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other Leaflet integrations for Vaadin 14+ available, like the one from XDev:

https://vaadin.com/directory/component/leafletmap-for-vaadin

Use that instead. I'm the author of the original v-leaflet library and when I get to upgrade my apps to Vaadin Flow based setup, I'll be using that as well (and will contribute to that if a certain feature is not available).